# How do I loop though names in the Settings file?

Tags: c#, loops, controls, identifier

I have a feeling this should be easy but I can't seem to figure it out. I have a settings file, Settings1.settings, that has entries for 20 textboxes (n1 thru n10 and c1 thru c10).

Currently, I save the textbox text to the settings file on Form1_FormClosing like so:

```
Settings1.Default.n1 = n1.Text;
Settings1.Default.n2 = n2.Text;
...
Settings1.Default.n10 = n10.Text;

Settings1.Default.c1 = c1.Text;
Settings1.Default.c2 = c2.Text;
...
Settings1.Default.c10 = c10.Text;
```

How would I do something similar with a loop? My thought would be this, but obviously it doesn't work:

```
int count = 1
while (count < 11)
{
    Control n = panel2.Controls.Find("n" + count.ToString(), true).Single();
    Settings1.Default.n = n.Text; //Settings1.Default.n is an invalid statement ...

    Control c = panel2.Controls.Find("c" + count.ToString(), true).Single();
    Settings1.Default.c = c.Text; //Settings1.Default.c is an invalid statement ...

    count++;
}
```

What's the proper way to address "Settings1.Default.n + count" ?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing the type of your settings "n" and "c" to "System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection" and dealing with it like a regular list or array object, something like:

```
Settings1.Default.n.Clear()
Settings1.Default.c.Clear()
int count = 1
while (count < 11)
{
    Control n = panel2.Controls.Find("n" + count.ToString(), true).Single();
    Settings1.Default.n.Add(n.Text);

    Control c = panel2.Controls.Find("c" + count.ToString(), true).Single();
    Settings1.Default.c.Add(c.Text);

    count++;
}
```

Alternatively, I think you can also access the settings entries by string like this:

```
Settings1.Default["n" + count.ToString()] = n.Text;
```

Comment: `Settings1.Default["n" + count.ToString()] = n.Text;` That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I will also look into changing the type

Answer (score 0):

bde's suggestion is undoubtedly the better way to do it, however, you could use the [GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103.aspx) method of `Type`. This can be used to get a collection of properties. You can then loop through them and use [PropertyInfo.SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291.aspx) to set them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConfigurationManager to read AppSettings. This is a NameValueCollection which you can query for specific keys (for example, keys which names start with "n" or "c"). You can also group your controls in a control array so that n[1] contains a reference to n1, n[2] to n2 and so on.